# Record too large for in-memory buffer. Error when working with Hive's ORC tables via TEZ

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc, tez

We are trying to read data from 'ORC' table in HIVE (1.2.1) and put that data into table with 'TextInputFormat'. Some entries are too large in original data and following error occurs during operation:

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter$MapBufferTooSmallException:
>   Record too large for in-memory buffer. Exceeded buffer overflow limit,
>   bufferOverflowRecursion=2, bufferList.size=1, blockSize=1610612736

Any ideas how to fix the issue?

We are using TEZ engine for queries execution and there are no errors with simple MR engine.

Query to execute:

```
insert overwrite table visits_text_test_1m select * from visits where dt='2016-01-19' limit 1000000;
```

Upd: Same error when copying from ORC to ORC storage.

Upd 2: Simple 'select' from ORC works pretty good with any engine.

Comment: Looks like a TEZ error - make that explicit in the title & the tags.

Comment: Thx for note, Samson!

Answer (score 0):

Hint #1: just switch from TEZ to MapReduce before running your query - slower but more resilient.

`set hive.execution.engine = mr ;`

Hint #2: since the exception comes out of the dreadful TEZ *ExternalSorter* beast, dig into TEZ properties such as `tez.runtime.sorter.class`, `tez.runtime.io.sort.mb` etc. Be warned that finding a working set of properties (not even speaking of tuning them to match your `hive.tez.container.size`) will probably require some kind of voodoo sacrifice.

Cf. HortonWork's [Configuring Tez](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_installing_manually_book/content/ref-ffec9e6b-41f4-47de-b5cd-1403b4c4a7c8.1.html) manual for starters.

Comment: 1. yup, I've tried MR for this query and it works well.


2. going to read more manuals :) but I'am wondering - is it even possible to make such data manipulations within HDFS with TEZ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"within HDFS"*? These props are set in `tez-site.xml` which is a local file expected in CLASSPATH of Hive CLI (or HiveServer2).

Comment: Note that the `hive.tez.*` props can be overriden dynamically inside a HQL script with a `set`command; but not the `tez.*` props which *must* be defined in `tez-site.xml`

Comment: by "within HDFS" I mean that I'm working with data stored in HDFS  :) by the way could you point manual that explains what kind of variables I can reload dynamically inside scripts and what I can't ?

Comment: also I have feeling that I should check some ORC settings since we can read from text and write to ORC, simply read from ORC, but we can't read from ORC and write to any storage if we are doing that in single query :P

Comment: posted full error log [http://pastebin.com/reKikjyt](http://pastebin.com/reKikjyt)

Answer (score 0):

like samson said you might want to increase the container size and also I found sometimes the JOIN does lead to the issue because by default the hive converts the join to MAPJOIN. You may want to try below settings in the query and see if it helps:

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;
set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask=false;
```

Comment: thx for idea! this settings don't solve my issue unfortunately, but advise about increasing sort buffer from Samson actually helps :)